# How to combine elements of a list into one element in Ocaml?

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to combine a list of integers into one integer in Ocaml.
For example,
Input - List = [2,3,6,7,9]
Desired Output - 97632.

I know how to iterate a list but what operation/function should I be using to get the desired output?

Comment: Look at `Printf.sprintf` or `Format.sprintf` (working like `printf` but returns a string instead of outputting to the standard output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time you're converting a list into another value, you should be looking at using either `List.fold_left` or `List.fold_right`.  It works the other way, but consider the below.

```
# List.fold_left (fun i x -> i ^ string_of_int x) "" [1;2;3;4];;
- : string = "1234"
#
```

See the list fold function documentation at https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Stdlib.List.html.

Alternatively, simply map the list of ints to a list of strings, and then use `String.concat`.

```
# [1; 2; 3; 4]
  |> List.map string_of_int
  |> String.concat "";;
- : string = "1234"
```